# changing letter into an encryption in java. simple call

Tags: java, syntax, ascii

What is the other way to change "a" to e.g."\n65" or other call in java which is based on ascii? this is not taught to java developers anymore but it was nice to know. i just forgot, but i need to use it for our project

Comment: `int dec = (int) c;`?

Comment: In what way is that encryption? And which bit of it are you stuck on? Just `"\\n" + (int) myChar` will do it...

Comment: Also that's a very poor encryption, I hope you're not developing a nuclear weapon program :)

Comment: Its just ascii value.. Don't call it encryption: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption

Comment: Acutally its \u0061 = a  so one and so forth, it is a primitive way to code i think. it is not a nuclear weapon program. :) not all know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acutally its \u0061 = a so one and so forth, it is a primitive way to code i think. it is not a nuclear weapon program. :) not all know this.